# Выбор нужной строки в sql

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
mark | material | pressure | id
"One"| "somemat"|"Pressure1"| 1
"Two"|"material2"|"Pressure2"|2
```

как мне выбрать необходимую строку со значением "One"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mark = "One"
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как сделать так, чтобы вместо конкретного значения (вместо "One") можно было вставить туда переменную?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE mark = {}".format('слово')  почитайте про форматирование строк в питоне

Comment: @Nobody, лучше не про форматирование расскажите, а про binding переменных в sql-запросах и про sql-инъекции ;)

Comment: @Nobody это вам нужно книжки по sql почитать, чтобы вы не писали больше тут откровенно вредных советов